# The Object Context instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Kindly tell me where I am doing a mistake I have seen StackOverflow same mistake but I am not finding my error after searchIng a lot.

This line Creates Error After Debugging
`@Model.Product.category.Name`

This is my front end

```
<div class="product-categories">
        <span>Categories: </span><a href="#">@Model.Product.category.Name</a>
</div>
```

my View model looks like

```
 public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Entities

````
 public class Product:BaseEntity
    {
        
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        //public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        public virtual Category category { get; set; }
       
    }
```[Ent][3]
[Front End where an error has been raised][1]
[My Entities image for your better understanding][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHRtx.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVsQQ.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXOa0.png
````

Comment: You have lazy loading enabled, and haven't included `category`.

Comment: @CodeCaster  Kindly go through the code I have been searching since last night but can understand what can I do.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have attached the Images also please review and tell me my mistakes

Comment: Somewhere you find the product in the database, using `dbContext.Products.Where(...)`. Change that into `dbContext.Products.Include(p => p.Category).Where(...)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster tHANKS FOR hELP ITS wORKING

Comment: @Sheikh Could you post the action too, pls?

Comment: @Sheikh Where are you converting the `Product` to `ProductViewModel`? Share the code of that part?

Comment: @Rahatur I am answering my Question wait for a while

Comment: @CodeCaster how do I vote you ThanKs for your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Product Service where I get Products and these lines of code are showing an error

Before Code

```
 public Product GetProduct(int ID)
            {
                using (var context = new TablesContext())
                {
                    return context.Products.Find(ID);
                }
            }
```

After Same code updated

```
 public Product GetProduct(int ID)
            {
                using (var context = new TablesContext())
                {
                    return context.Products.Where(x => x.id == ID).Include(x => x.category).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
```

this line of code updated from this  `return context.Products.Find(ID);`
to this
`return context.Products.Where(x => x.id == ID).Include(x => x.category).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for helping